# How to create Android game that if user passed level1 ,user reach to level2

Tags: android-activity

I am beginner .Please help me example code.
I want to explain this problem.
Game has 3Activity.
1.MenuActivity  2.ActivityA  3.ActivityB
MenuActivity has 2 Button for ActovityA and ActivityB.
 Button1 for ActivityA always open.But Button2 for
ActivityB can open ,user  passed ActivityA  .

Answer (score 2):

You need an if statement:

```
if user.level  (Or some custom selector) > 2 {

//button 2 is opened action

}
```

you need to furthermore explain your question.